# Why is five electrons in d orbital more stable than seven electrons / eight electrons?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

The half filled and full filled configuration is considered to be most the stable among the other configurations. But d7 or d8 configuration has a greater exchange energy mathematically. So why isn't it considered to be more stable than d5 configuration which is half filled configuration?

Comment: Stability is never defined in absolute terms and I don't think that a generalised statement can be made. So, I'm afraid you must be a lot more specific about what you are actually asking.